# Python 3 Indices Negativos

Tags: python-3.x

Então, pessoal. Sou novo em python e queria saber o seguinte:

Tem alguma forma de saber qual o indice negativo de um item numa lista?

Por exemplo, tenho o seguinte código:

```
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
lista.index('a')
0
lista.index('g')
6
```

Gostaria de saber se existe algum método que retorne o indice de trás pra frente, desta forma:

```
lista.index('g')
-1
lista.index('a')
-7
```

Não consegui achar nada parecido com isso.

Comment: `lista.index('a') - len(lista)`?

Comment: Obrigado!! Funcionou :D

Comment: ... ou usar a lista inversa `-lista[::-1].index('a')-1` (ignorem: estou a brincar às charadas!)

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com o comentário do @bfavaretto, a resposta é:

```
lista.index('a') - len(lista)
```

Comment: Só precisa verificar se existe mesmo o índice de `'a'`

Comment: Como comentário é bom, como resposta seria conveniente elaborar um pouco mais.

Answer (score 0):

`def returnOpposite(li):
    for i in range(len(li) - 1, -1, -1):
        print(f'Your element is: {li[i]}, Your opposite index: {i * -1 -1}')`

returnOpposite(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])

isso resolve o problema, a função basicamente está percorrendo a lista ao contrario e printando o index multiplicando por -1, para deixar da maneira que você propôs

Answer (score -1):

Os índices vão de 0 até a quantidade de elementos adicionados.

exemplo:

```
listaN1 = [1,2,3]
""" três pontos (...) é uma Ellipsi , omissão de valor. """
#ou
listaN2 = 'abc' #String em python tbm pode ser lista.

índice = valor           índice = valor 
  0    =  1                 0   =  a
  1    =  2                 1   =  b
  2    =  3                 2   =  c
```

Acessar usando índice negativo retornava a lista de trás para frente.

```
    índice = valor           índice = valor 
     -1    =  3                 -1  =  c
     -2    =  2                 -2  =  b
     -3    =  1                 -3  =  a
```

#Zero em zero não chegava em lugar nenhum, o zero negativo é o índice do primeiro elemento.

Exemplo Manipulando a lista:

```
listaN1[**iniciar** : *parar* : **pular**]

listaN1[0:2)]
retorno = dois primeiros elementos, 
listaN1[0:3)]
retorno = três elementos
# OU
listaN1[:2] #OMITIR O PRIMEIRO VALOR, CONSIDERA ZERO

listaN1[2:3] # ultimo elemento.
#pulando  posições, como não digitei muitos numero vera nenhuma diferença.
listaN1[1::3]

#INVERTENDO VALORES, MENOR PARA O MAIOR.
listaN1[::-1]
```